# Permission denied to access property 'type'

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that is being handled with jQuery for an AJAX request, and I'm getting an error in the console;

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'type'

in the `jquery.min.js` file on line 5, col 3395.

**jQuery**

```
<script language="javascript">
(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emvForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email, nm;

        email = $('#emailfield').val;
        nm = $('#namefield').val;

        if (email != '' && nm != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/ajax/enewsletter_subscribe',
                data: {
                    'email': email,
                    'name': nm,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#form-nlfm').slideUp(200).html('<h2>Thank You</h2><p class="text-center">You are now signed up to our mail list.</p>').slideDown(500);
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="" id="emvForm" method="POST" name="emvForm" role="form" target="_top">
 <div class="result"></div>
 <div class="form-area col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" id="form-nlfm">
 <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="namefield" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>
 <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="emailfield" maxlength="64" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>
 <p class="text-center"><button id="nlfm-submit" class="submit button">Subscribe</button></p>
 </div>
</form>
```

I've tried changing selectors, renaming variables, and other similar things.

Comment: I can't see how it would create that symptom, but this and the others like it are wrong: `email = $('#emailfield').val;` jQuery's `val` is a *function*, you have to call it: `email = $('#emailfield').val();`

Comment: It's line 5 and col 3395 of the `jquery.min.js` file.

Comment: Then the next step is to use the unminified file and see where the error is *really* occurring. I can't see anything amiss above at all other than the `val` thing I highlighted. Try to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), that usually flags up the problem.

Comment: Looks like it was the problem with val!

Comment: How...interesting! What a truly bizarre symptom. And it really doesn't make sense, you're passing an object to `ajax` as `data` so it should get serialized correctly. I can't see why...huh. I wonder if it tries to *call* the function? Anyway, glad it's sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have this:

```
email = $('#emailfield').val;
nm = $('#namefield').val;
```

It should be this, because jQuery's `val` is a function:

```
email = $('#emailfield').val();
nm = $('#namefield').val();
```